# How to improve wordpress site creation process to increase productivity.

Tags: php, front-end

**more info:** we are all here working and loving WordPress but at the end of the day we need to make money if we can finish same work in less time we can be more competitive and take more projects in same time.

I know maybe each one of you has his secrets so I will start by talking about what I was doing in the last couple of years.

**my process:**
I start from the design I make it in photoshop show to client revisions till we reach final design I start working on the front end and create the theme directly in WordPress . and here is the part I want to improve.

my current process I have a starter theme that I created it has all the basic stuff that you need for each site ACF, FA, Bootstrap, JQuery, google fonts, other plugins, and CSS libraries I created Atom CSS library and OO CSS libraries.
I take a copy via Duplicator plugin install it to the server then start creating the pages and other stuff ... let's say I have a personal website with any design with 5 pages it will take 3 days or about 24hours to go from PSD image to working WordPress site. news website about 1 week,

now I am working on a new system 
for example header, each header design will be in separated PHP file with its CSS and JS and same goes to each block with special design than when I create a website will start calling the blocks with the most similar design then add edit them to go with the design 
finally, all the CSS and JS is merged in real time in one file and compressed 
in this way, I may finish the simple personal site in like 4-5 hours 
and each project I finish will have some new blocks will add them to the library since each block in a separate PHP file and have separated CSS and JS will not affect the performance if I don't call the block its just some files on the server. I did not finish the system yet :( that's why I am asking the Question maybe there is a better way !? and I am overkilling it!

**so guys what are you doing and what the process you are following in creating WordPress websites !?**

**NOTE:** I don't use ready themes and will never use them please don't mention them at all.

**NOTE2:** I searched the web most articles I found are very very basic like do design do front end linkWordPressress make it dynamic !! omg really ! you dont say ! and in stackOverFlow, there was no single article !?

Comment: if you have more and more habits when working with wordpress, it's a good idea searching to spare time like creating a clone with duplicator and removing what is not usefull. my job is to write plugins and to be more efficient I have created a plugin with all function a use regularly.

Comment: downvoted as this is a general software development question which is not even specific to web development, and actually has way more than 10 possible answers

Answer (score 0):

I think your method sounds solid and with custom, hand-designed websites your time frame is quite reasonable. We primarily use the Divi theme which is highly customizable and it still takes us few days to get from concept to launch. The vast majority of time is in the fine details and tweaks, and those are the qualities that change an okay website to a great website.